# mySQL 'SELECT' limit to variable string

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE thecolum = thevar;
```

My actual command is:

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls WHERE mstlistbrd = 3675E4340E0560;
```

The console is kicking back at me with:

```
"ERROR 1367 (22007): Illegal double '3675E4340' value found during parsing
```

Reading this, I see two things:

1. It's finding the value twice (which I want because I want it to pull all the rows for that value.
2. It's cutting off the value 5 digits short.

Is it only going to the 9th digit of the value for some reason other than it found a duplicate?  How to I get it to print the duplicate values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around your string

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls WHERE mstlistbrd = '3675E4340E0560'
```

Without them it tries to interpret it as number which fails and gives you the error you got.